# How to change a belongs to attribute of a model in controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my Ember application using ember-data and JSONAPISerializer, I have a task model and a priority model. A task belongs to a priority and a priority can have many tasks associated with it.

The models are as follows

***app/model/task.js***

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr ('string'),
    description: DS.attr ('string'),
    isComplete: DS.attr ('boolean'),
    priority: DS.belongsTo('priority')
});
```

***app/models/priority.js***

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr ('string'),
    description: DS.attr ('string'),
    tasks: DS.hasMany ('task'),
});
```

The user can edit the task and change any attribute including its priority. This is handled in the controller.

The editing form has a dropdown from which the priority can be selected. This drop down is populated by the controller by querying the store.

I have got the editing and saving part to work for all attributes except the priority. I am not able to make the changed priority stick when saving the task.

What I have tried is query the store for priority with title matching the selected value in the dropdown and set that in the model.

The code in the controller on my first attempt was as follows and that did not work.

```
var newPriority = this.get('store').queryRecord('priority', {
    filter: {
        title: newPriorityTitle
    }
});
this.get('model').set('priority', newPriority);
```

How to change the priority before saving the model?

**Update:**

I changed the initial code to the one below and that seems to work

```
this.get('store').queryRecord('priority', {
    filter: {
        title: newPriorityTitle
    }
}).then(function(data) {
    this.get('model').set('priority', data);
});
```

Comment: How do you set priority for the task?

Comment: I query the store for priority with the title value from the dropdown and then try to set that onto the model which does not work. Details added in my original question.

Comment: Maybe your code for setting priority help us. But `task.set('priority', selectedPriority);` should work

Comment: `store.query` returns `RecordArray`. You should set one object not enumerable like

Comment: Thanks for that tip Ebrahim. Pardon my ignorance but how would I achieve that? Should I use "queryRecord" instead for "query"?

Comment: You have priority id, so `store.findRecord('priority', selectedId);`. And another thing is because you load all priorities so you don't need to fetching from server, and `store.peekRecord('priority', selectedId);` is enough

Comment: I tried using queryRecord but the content is null in Ember Inspecter when I log the new value to console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because this.store.queryRecord(...) doesn't return the record (immediately), it returns a promise.

You have to do:

```
newPriority.then((priorityObj) => {
  this.model.set('priority', priorityObj);
}
```

Comment: if you don't care that data may have changed, you could change your code to say peekRecord (since you've probably already loaded the priorities in the store to populate your drop-down) and then it returns synchronously and you don't have to wrap in a then...again, only if you're not concerned that the priority record you have in the store hasn't changed since you loaded it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Robert, that is what I did and got it to work.